# wordpress - same tab content displaying for products in same category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing a weird problem and it has consumed all my time. I am working on a plugin based on woocommerce. For this I have added code snippet from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382005/woocommerce-showing-same-product-tabs-data-for-all-products) for loading woocommerce templates from my plugin folder and I am successfull in same.

The problem is when I have multiple products in same product category I can see that all the product pages are displaying same tab content like `description` and `comments` (product reviews). This happens only when I have a comment posted for any of the products.

I noticed that `tabs.php` on woocommerce templates is loading only one product id irrespective of what product it should display. Can anyone help me solving this?

**UPDATE 1**

My understanding was wrong that this issue ocurring only when products are in same category. Instead this issue is showing up when the products post author is same for the noticed products.